# Proving addition of rational numbers is well defined

Tags: arithmetic, rational-numbers

I am trying to show that the addition of rational numbers is well defined.
Does anyone know if this is a legitimate strategy?
Also, I am quite unfamiliar with coding on here.
Q is defined as $Q = \{m/n: m, n \in Z, n \ne 0\}$
where $m/n$ is the class of ordered pairs $(m,n)$ such that $(m,n)\equiv (p,q)$ if $mq = pn$ with $n, q \ne 0$.

Statement: If $(a,b) \equiv (a',b')$ and $(c,d) \equiv (c',d')$, then $(ad+bc,bd) \equiv (a'd'+b'c',b'd')$.
Proof:
Assumptions:
$(a,b) \equiv (a',b')$ implies $ab'=ba'$, which then implies $ab'-ba'=0$.
$(c,d) \equiv (c',d')$ implies $cd'=dc'$, which then implies $dc'-cd'=0$.

Since $ab'-ba'=0$, this implies $dd'(ab'-ba')=0$, also $bb'(dc'-cd')=0$ with similar reasoning.
Since $dd'(ab'-ba')=0$ and $bb'(dc'-cd')=0$, this implies $dd'(ab'-ba')=bb'(dc'-cd')$.

Now some algebraic manipulations
$ab'dd'-ba'dd'=dc'bb'-cd'bb'$
$ab'dd'-a'bdd'=c'dbb'-cd'bb'$
$ab'dd'+cd'bb'=a'bdd'+c'dbb'$
$adb'd'+bcb'd'=bda'd'+bdb'c'$
$(ad+bc)b'd'=bd(a'd'+b'c')$

Which implies, $(ad+bc,bd) \equiv (a'd'+b'c',b'd')$
Please let me know if this is legitimate. I worked backwards a lot in order to manipulate in just the right way.

Comment: It's a lot of work to define this correctly. It seems to me that you can find a complete and accessible explanation in the famous "Cours de mathématiques du premier cycle-première année" by Jacques Dixmier published by Gauthier-villars in 1976 (second edition). In his paragraph 4.6, you will find your last equality for example (4.6.5) and the application of his more general reasoning to Q constructed from the ring Z(4.6.7).

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble seeing all the primes but in general the method looks good to me. Somewhere you should mention the restriction that the denominators b, b', d, d' are not zero.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I'm going to Grad school next year, so I'm trying to get a head start by watching lectures on youtube. This was a homework problem given by the lecturer, and I wanted to make sure my understanding was accurate.

Comment: I tried grad school but unfortunately it didn't take. My respiratory failure, at that time not yet diagnosed, undermined me. I have to get a portable oxygen machine and try again to see if I can breathe in the windowless seminar rooms, :-)
Good luck to you.

Comment: Dang, I hope you can get what you need in order to pursue your degree!                                                                                                            Good luck to you too!